# ManipulationCompleted in UniversalApps(WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8, touch

I am trying to implement drag and drop feature. My problem is that ManipulationCompleted event is fired too late. When I make a fast move with my finger and release touch, my object is flying for about half a second longer. I want to prevent invoking OnManipulationDelta exactly when my finger is released.

```
 private void UIElement_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Changed");
            var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                TranslateTransform transform = element.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
                if (transform != null)
                {
                    transform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Touch_FrameReported.

Is a low level method and has little overhead and is very precise : [Touch.FrameReported Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.input.touch.framereported(v=vs.105).aspx)

Example :

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(this.CanvasLayer);

        if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            if (GestureType.Hold == gesture.GestureType)
            {
                IsActiveTouch = true;
                StartMoveWheel(point.Position);
                HoldWheel(sender, e);
            }
            else
            {
                this.CanvasLayer.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                IsActiveTouch = false;
            }
        }

        if (IsActiveTouch)
        {
            //Test if touch control is CanavasLayer
            if (point.TouchDevice.DirectlyOver == this.CanvasLayer)
            {
                switch (point.Action)
                {
                    case TouchAction.Move:
                        if (point != null) MoveWheel(point.Position);
                        break;
                    case TouchAction.Up:
                    default:
                        ExecuteCompletedMoveWheel();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ExecuteCompletedMoveWheel();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution wasturning off inertia ;)
I've done it changing ManipulationMode from All to TranslateX (because I want to translate my element only on X axis)